# Shortcut key for context sensitive help for Eclipse in Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos

What is the shortcut key for context sensitive help(Just like (F1) in windows) in eclipse for Mac OS X.

I have tried (shift+command+ ?) and (command+ ?) but none of them works.

Any thoughts on this ? Is there any other way to achieve the same.

Best Regards,
Kondal Kolipaka

Answer (score 0):

try this shortcut, works for me.

shift+command+/

Comment: I tried this, but it points to 'Help' Search. Are you getting context help just like F1 in windows ? Have you configured any dynamic command ?

Comment: For me it opens dynamic help as I get from F1 in windows and i haven't configured any dynamic command.

Comment: make sure you have correct help preferences.
open help search --> in the dynamic help view, 
open help view documents --> in place, 
open help contents --> in the help browser, 

open window context help --> in the dynamic help view, 
open dialog context help --> in a dialog tray.